# Is there a way to ensure a string in an ARM template doesn't get too long

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I'm using ARM templates to create deployment slots on our webapps, and I seem to have run into a problem when the host name bindings are defined. I extractred a template from Azure and then modified it to use variables, but when I deploy I get an error:

```bsh
Too many (2) hostnames in the default DNS zone. Limit is 1.
```

After a bit of investigation, I found out that Azure truncates the assigned custom domain to [domain-name-up-to-40-characters]-staging.azurewebsites.net, meaning that the domain names don't match. So I tried the following in my ARM template:

```
"type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/slots/hostNameBindings",
"apiVersion": "[variables('myWebapp').apiVersion]",
"name": "[concat(variables('myWebapp').name, '/staging/', substring(variables('myWebapp').name, 0, 40), '-staging', parameters('domain'))]",
```

That does the trick, but only if the name of the app is 40 characters or more. When the name goes below that, I get this error message:

```
The index and length parameters must refer to a location within the string. The index parameter: '0', the length parameter:  '40', the length of the string parameter: '38'
```

Looking at the documentation, substring() will fail if the string is shorter, but I would really like to let the ARM template handle things like this instead of having contraints on the name of the apps. Is there some reasonable workaround that I have missed? I guess using conditional parameters where i check length() might work, but that will make the templates swell a bit.

Comment: what about using the `maxLength` property: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-authoring-templates#parameters

Comment: The problem is that the names of the different apps are quite dynamic and will be build up with parameters from the build system. Each app will consist 3-4 different parts, meaning that all other parts can build and deploy, but then suddenly the deployment slots throw an error. In our setup, that's a bit too late, that's why I wanted the template itself to take care of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think this is the closest you can get:

```
if(greater(length(your-parameter-goes-here), 40), do-substring, return-original-value)
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with the 'take' function in ARM.

This will take up-to the first 16 chars of the string for the name....
"[take(parameters('storageAccountName'), 16))]"

It doesn't care if the string is less than 16 chars, but will truncate it if it's longer.

Answer (score 1):

**Take()** function is the way to go, avaibale in bicep and ARM template:

**take(originalValue, numberToTake)**

"The number of elements or characters to take. If this value is 0 or less, an empty array or string is returned. If it's larger than the length of the given array or string, all the elements in the array or string are returned."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-string#take

Answer (score 0):

Using if() as suggested worked better than I thought, even if it gets a bit messy. As a reference if anybody else runs into this problem, this is how it ended up:

`"name": "[if(greater(length(variables('myWebapp').name), 39), concat(variables('myWebapp').name, '/staging/', substring(variables('myWebapp').name, 0, 40), '-staging', parameters('domain')), concat(variables('myWebapp').name, '/staging/', variables('myWebapp').name, '-staging', parameters('domain')))]"`

Comment: yeah, it looks quite horrible, but not much you can do about it, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

What you also can do is first make the string long enough to survive the substring, and then remove the padding characters again in case it was shorter to start with.

You need the padding char because there is also no padRight. In my case the padding-char was just a space since that would have been an illegal char anyway in the given context.

> [replace(substring(padLeft(your-string,maxlength,padding-char),0,maxlengt),
> padding-char,'')]